# How to disable update of chromedriver or how to set user-agent of last version of chromedriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

I need the driver to work under the specific user-agent. I previously used a 
chromedriver v 2.27. Here so installed user-agent:

```
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.AddArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 
     like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko)
     Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");
```

But it does not work in **chromedriver v 2.32**, which is constantly updated by every compiling of Selenium project.

How to set user-agent on chromedriver v2.32 or how to disable auto-update, because disabling the browser update (in several ways) did not help?

Comment: Which upgrade you can't control,  browser, webdriver or Selenium jars?  If you can't control the browser upgrade,  you have to find out  how to set user-agent on new webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(string.Format("--user-agent={0}", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0  like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3"));
```

You just lose "--".